# Why does Batroc want revenge on Falcon?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-the-winter-soldier, the-falcon-and-the-winter-soldier

In episode 5 of *The Falcon and the Winter Soldier*, a certain character enlists the mercenary Batroc to attack Falcon, luring him with the promise of revenge. But AFAIK Batroc was captured and taken off the field in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* before Sam even got involved. What would Batroc’s beef be?

Comment: Did you miss him being defeated by Falcon in episode 1? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocp8jSqCTJM

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Batroc is the mercenary in charge of the plane-jacking and kidnapping of Captain Vassant at the start of *The Falcon and the Winter Soldier* which Sam intercepts and puts an end to. We see his face clearly a few times.

[image: Batroc leans into the cockpit]

Comment: That'll teach me not to rewatch. I did check an MCU wiki which listed Batroc's details in Falcon and the Winter Soldier as "pending," which sold me on the idea that he hadn't showed up yet.